# Delete from multiple tables (use condition from first table)

Tags: mysql

This has prob been answered before but I could not find it.

I have 6 tables where I need to delete 15768 rows from each.

The tables are named feed_7 to feed_12, for the first table I find the records to delete with this statement:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `feed_7` 
WHERE `data` > 80
```

The table is simple with a time and data column.

[image]

For `feed_8` to `feed_12` I only have the time values from the first table

But how do I delete the rows in `feed_8` to `feed_12` that meets the condition from the first table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join `feed_7` to the other tableswith `LEFT` joins:

```
DELETE f7, f8, f9, f10, f11, f12 
FROM feed_7 f7 
LEFT JOIN feed_8 f8 ON f8.time = f7.time
LEFT JOIN feed_9 f9 ON f9.time = f7.time
LEFT JOIN feed_10 f10 ON f10.time = f7.time
LEFT JOIN feed_11 f11 ON f11.time = f7.time
LEFT JOIN feed_12 f12 ON f12.time = f7.time
WHERE f7.data > 80
```

Comment: i know its possible to do a simulation but it escapes me how this time

i wanted to do that so i know what will happen before i actual do it

Comment: i tried to use select instead of delete just to try it out and i got an error

https://imgur.com/a/LjI4Hxg

Comment: SELECT * 
FROM feed_7 f7 
LEFT JOIN feed_8 f8 ON f8.time = f7.time
LEFT JOIN feed_9 f9 ON f9.time = f7.time
LEFT JOIN feed_10 f10 ON f10.time = f7.time
LEFT JOIN feed_11 f11 ON f11.time = f7.time
LEFT JOIN feed_12 f12 ON f12.time = f7.time
WHERE f7.data > 80

Comment: that looks like ok, and i guess all i have to do now is replace SELECT with DELETE ?

Comment: No, the DELETE syntax is like the code in my answer.

Comment: Fine and don't forget to accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark if it solved your problem.

Comment: done :-D and i found that there where rows in feed_8 that was also wrong and i changed your answer to:

DELETE f7, f8, f9, f10, f11, f12 
    FROM feed_7 f7 
    LEFT JOIN feed_8 f8 ON f8.time = f7.time
    LEFT JOIN feed_9 f9 ON f9.time = f7.time
    LEFT JOIN feed_10 f10 ON f10.time = f7.time
    LEFT JOIN feed_11 f11 ON f11.time = f7.time
    LEFT JOIN feed_12 f12 ON f12.time = f7.time
    WHERE f7.data > 80

Comment: that was what i tought i did

FROM feed_7 f7 changed to FROM feed_8 f8

LEFT JOIN feed_8 f8 ON f8.time changed to LEFT JOIN feed_7 f7 ON f7.time

all f7.time at the end of the lines changed to f8.time

last line WHERE f7.data > 80 changed to WHERE f8.data > 80

Comment: its a shame that comments cant be formatted like your answer is so i made a picture of it in a markdown formatting tool

https://imgur.com/a/VJYygcu